# Read Model in JSP as Java Variable

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have this in my JSP,

```
<c:forEach items="${files}" var="f">
                <li>
                    <a href="">${f}</a>
                </li>
</c:forEach>
```

I need to access files as a Java variable. So, I can manipulate this.

Got it using, request.getAttribute("files");

Comment: Where is the object pointing to files added to page, request, session, or application scope?  It doesn't appear by magic.

Comment: @duffymo, In Spring MVC Model

Comment: Is "files" one of the keys in your Spring ModelAndView?  It's probably a list of String, right?  You don't pass java.io.File instances, because they aren't the same on the client and server.

Comment: @duffymo, files is add using ModelMap.addObject("files", results); where results is List<string>

Comment: @user960567 Why you not manipulate in Controller?

Comment: @duffymo, Got it using, request.getAttribute("files");

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate it with jstl as well.

```
<c:set var="f" value="Somthing else..." />
```

If you want to access the variable java I think you can do

```
<% String f = (String)pageScope.getAttribute("f"); %>
```

Comment: Got it using, request.getAttribute("files");